# Mulesoft DataWeave: How to escape $ for quoted string

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

...I'm using Anypoint Studio 7.6 and writing in DataWeave 2.0

I cannot find the definitive way to include the $ (dollar sign) character in a quoted string.

Here's what I tried:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var sign = "\u0024" // unicode dollar sign
type currency = String {format: "$sign ###.00"} // interpolation from previous var
var cost = 100 as currency
---
{
    directly: "a dollar sign like this: \$",
    asdefined: sign,
    indirectly: "This flight, costs $(cost), and is operated by " 
       ++ payload.airline
}
```

Here's what I got for my trouble:

```
{
  directly: "a dollar sign like this: \$",
  asdefined: "\$",
  indirectly: "This flight, costs \$ 100.00, and is operated by United"
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi There is no problem with what you see it is just that you are using application/dw as output. In that format the `$` need to be escaped that is why you see it like that. If you change to `application/json` they will disappear.

Comment: ...that is so helpful! And hilarious. I always tell people to use application/dw while coding because it's mostly forgiving of data format errors. But I should have considered that it would try to show me a little too much. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record, application/dw should only be used for troubleshooting, not as a 'standard' format. It has a performance and compatibility impact. Using it by default has the risk of forgetting it is there, and it looks similar enough to JSON that it is not obvious.

Answer (score 3):

This may be just because your output is application/dw. Once you switch to application/json or other mime-type the escaping should work correctly.